# Flutter bool name = String its possible?

Tags: flutter, boolean

Hey i make a Favorite System with a bool to say if is favorite or not.

But if the name of the bool is always the same it applies to all my entries!

but each entry has its own name (widget.name), and i thought maybe something like that could work

```
bool widget.name;
```

but this not work :(

how can i solve that each entry has its own bool?

by the way i use this plugin for that
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
bool isfavorit;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences sp) {
      sharedPreferences = sp;
      isfavorit = sharedPreferences.getBool(spKey);
      // will be null if never previously saved
      if (isfavorit == null) {
        isfavorit = false;
        persist(isfavorit); // set an initial value
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

    void persist(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isfavorit = value;
    });
    sharedPreferences?.setBool(spKey, value);
  }
```

Complete Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Details extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;

  Details(
    this.name,
  );

  @override
  _DetailsState createState() => _DetailsState();
}

const String spKey = 'myBool';

class _DetailsState extends State<Details> {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  bool isfavorit;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences sp) {
      sharedPreferences = sp;
      isfavorit = sharedPreferences.getBool(spKey);
      // will be null if never previously saved
      if (isfavorit == null) {
        isfavorit = false;
        persist(isfavorit); // set an initial value
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void persist(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isfavorit = value;
    });
    sharedPreferences?.setBool(spKey, value);
  }

// ignore: missing_return
  IconData favicon() {
    if (isfavorit == true) {
      return Icons.favorite;
    } else if (isfavorit == false) {
      return Icons.favorite_border;
    }
  }

// ignore: missing_return
  Color favicolor() {
    if (isfavorit == true) {
      return Colors.red;
    } else if (isfavorit == false) {
      return Colors.white;
    }
  }

  void changefav() {
    if (isfavorit == true) {
      return persist(false);
    } else if (isfavorit == false) {
      return persist(true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              favicon(),
              color: favicolor(),
            ),
            onPressed: () => changefav(),
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(widget.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Text(widget.name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code that you have.

Comment: Can you share the whole widget

Comment: Have update the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always saving the `isFavorite` to the same key in shared preferences, instead of using a constant key use one that is based on the `widget.name`

So for instance:

```dart
sharedPreferences.getBool('details_favorite_${widget.name}');
```

Comment: where exactly do I have to use it or replace it?

Comment: everywhere where you use `spKey` use `'details_favorite_${widget.name}'` instead

Comment: Nice that work :) now how i can load all saved bool names in a list vie listbuilder? and in other page?

Comment: Checkout the [getKeys](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/getKeys.html) method of shared preferences

Comment: ok thanks but i'm still a real beginner could you give me an example of code how i can implement it?

Comment: To learn it's better to first try some things yourself (even without an example and just some documentation). If you then cannot get it to work you can post another question just like this one with how far you got and where you get stuck

Comment: the documentation is not helpful for a beginner because it shows no code examples at all, it assumes that you already know, and I don't know where to start :(